The smallest number of step to sort $n$ numbers
The problem is

The numbers from $1$ to $n$ are in a line in some order. In each step, we can choose a pair of numbers $(a,b)$ and swap them if $a>b$ and $a$ is on the left of $b$ (not necessary consecutive). Our goal is to turn all the numbers in order $1,2,3,\dots,n$.


Prove that we can do it in finite steps.
What is the biggest number of steps we can make?
What is the smallest number of steps we need to sort them numbers which work for all initial position?

The first one is easy, there are at most $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ pair of numbers $(a,b)$ such that $a>b$ and $a$ is on the left of $b$. Each step, I bring down (at least) one such pair so the progression must end in finite steps.
The second one is obviously $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ since the progression ends in at most $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ steps. I just need to consider the initial position as
$$n \;\;\; (n-1) \;\;\; \dots \;\;\; 2 \;\;\; 1$$
and then bring $1$ down to the first position by $n-1$ steps, bring $2$ down to the second position by $n-2$ steps and so on. The total number of steps is
$$(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+1=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
The third part is the one I concern the most. The answer should be $n-1$ since I just need bring $1$ to the first position by $1$ step and then bring $2$ to the second position by $1$ step and so on.
Did I make a mistake? Is the answer $n-1$ steps? Which initial position that I need exactly $n-1$ steps to sort?

There are many well known, although slightly complicated, sorting algorithms that are guaranteed to take at most $n \log n$ steps. If you give a better idea of the context you're approaching this problem from people will be better able to help.

Note:  "bubble sorting", one of the most well known simple sorting algorithm, only lets you swap adjacent pairs.  If you look at the duplicate, you'll see they consider both that case and the non-adjacent variant you speak of.

Should say that simply counting the swaps doesn't capture the complexity of your variant.  To execute your variant efficiently, you need to analyze the cycle structure of your permutation..not computationally efficient.

The specifics of this problem suggest to me that you can choose which numbers to swap without cost for examining them. That's rather different from the usual computer-science sorting problem, where "swaps" are not the only cost. I therefore think that closing this question was a mistake.

@JohnHughes  Unless I have misunderstood, the duplicate does exactly what the OP asks for...that is, it counts the number of swaps needed.  Specifically, it shows that the number is $n-k$ if the permutation has $k$ disjoint cycles (confirming the OP's thought that the worst case was $n-1$).  I agree that the OP did not bring up any other sources of computational complexity.  I only alluded to them because another commenter brought up the computational complexity of other sorting algorithms.

Fair enough. The other comments mis-led me into thinking the related question was all about typical big-O analyses of bubble (and other) sorts.
